# How can I call ajax, without "link_to" kind of helpers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, ajax

I have a block like :

```
      - competitors.each do |competitor|
        %dl
          %dt
            ...
          %dd
            %span{:id => "#{competitor['watchers']}"}= "#{((competitor['watchers']*100.0)/30000).round.to_f}%"
```

note that it generate dinamic CSS id, one each block clicle, resoulting html is a list of different dd --> span --> id number :

```
<dl>
  <dt>
    ...
    <dd>
      <span id="774">93.0%</span>
    </dd>
  </dt>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>
    ... 
    <dd>
      <span id="13774">46.0%</span>
    </dd>
  </dt>
</dl>
```

I want to "dinamically" associate "custom CSS snippets", to the different css ids ( #13774  #774 ), something like :

```
:javascript
  $("##{competitor['watchers']}").css({ width: "#{((competitor['watchers']*100)/30000)}px" });
```

How can I call ajax (in Rails 3.2.3 ':remote => true' ) without link_to kind of helpers ?

Untill now I tried just calling JS from inner block like :

```
      - competitors.each do |competitor|
        :javascript
          $("##{competitor['watchers']}").css({ width: "#{((competitor['watchers']*100)/30000)}px" });
        %dl
          %dt
            ...
          %dd
            %span{:id => "#{competitor['watchers']}"}= "#{((competitor['watchers']*100.0)/30000).round.to_f}%"
```

but it doesn't work, the code is never injected into the DOM.

Comment: Can you use the :remote => true option in link_to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to show some kind of bar graph, and in that case, I would suggest the following (I'm assuming you are using jQuery as that's what's tagged):

Change your block to add a unique class to each span.  This gives you style benefits later.

```
%dd
        %span{:id => "#{competitor['watchers']}", :class => "progress-bar"}= "#{((competitor['watchers']*100.0)/30000).round.to_f}%"
```

Then you should be able to use some jQuery at the bottom of the page to select each one, and do some basic math on it:

```
$('span.progress-bar').each(function(index,element){
    var num = $(element).attr('id'); // get element id
    var width = parseInt(num * 100 / 30000); // do your math, then get the integer value for width
    $(element).css('width',width+'px'); // set width
}
```

I know you were looking for ajax, but unless I'm missing something, this should come close to solving your issues as documented.

Comment: Sorry Luca, did you put the javascript inside of the html.erb page, or did you add it to the rails code?  I would add it to the bottom of the html.erb page this goes in, since it will run as soon as the browser sees it, and you need all of the elements on the page already before it will work.  Does that help?

Comment: You also don't need this in your competitors.each loop, you want it after that.

Comment: I already put js to the bottom of html.haml and droped js off competitors.each loop, but still miss something ... I can't see the "injected width+'px' " into html/css resulting page ... to be correct I'd expect to see <span style="width: 47%" class="progress-bar" id="13774">46.0%</span> after js action, instead I just see <span id="13774" class="progress-bar">46.0%</span>